# EF Core not passing in primary key to query

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-core-2.2

I am converting my project to .NET Core (and EF Core).

When I call `SaveChanges`, I can see that my entity is listed as a modified entity (to be inserted).  And the primary key is listed as a set value.

But when I look at the SQL that it outputs, the primary key is not listed among the properties that it sets.

Here is an example of my Entity:

```
[Table("Bag", Schema = "Shipment")]
public partial class Bag
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(11)]
    public string BagNumber { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Box")]
    public long BoxId { get; set; }
    public virtual Box Box { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpened { get; set; }
    // ... More stuff below
```

Entity Framework Core makes a merge statement out of the insert.  As I said above, it does not have my primary key in the query (in this case BagNumber).

I thought that perhaps .NET Core assumed that all keys are autogenerated on the database.  To test this I tried setting `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` on the key.  But that gave me an error about using a temporary value for my key (not sure what that is about).

I verified that SaveChanges is getting the primary key (BagNumber) by overriding SaveChanges and iterating through the added and modified entities.

Not sure what else to try.  (Note: This all worked fine in Entity Framework 6.)

**How can I get Entity Framework Core to not strip out my primary key?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF core uses Autogenerated (autoincrement) field for primary keys by default. If you want to change this behaviour you can use

`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` or
`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` or
`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`

attributes on the key property.

But you must ensure that the database provider you use supports this attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't have correct definition of keys in your entity. If you want to set identity by sql server, property type must be numeric

```
public class Bag
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
public int BagNumber { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("BoxId")]
public virtual Box Box { get; set; }
public long BoxId { get; set; }

public bool IsOpened { get; set; }
// ... More stuff below
```

Another approach set key by your codes before save changes

Comment: It is not an identity or an int (or any kind of number as far as data type goes.)  Don't let the column name confuse you.  It is a string that is called BagNumber.  (This is 
a string (varchar) because it can have leading zeros that must be maintained to match barcode scans.)  It is a `varchar(11)` column.

Comment: I set the value before save changes is called.  That is why I can see it set in the SaveChanges method.  But EF Core is not transferring it to the generated SQL.

Comment: I recommended you to add new key for this entity as Id because primary key must be unique and for use as foreign key store numeric values is more better

Comment: You can set BagNumber as Index column but not key, that's very useful for search performamce